# Arraylist what am i actually doing here

Tags: arraylist

Suppose am in a class

`public class Foo{
//some fields
ArrayList fooList = new ArrayList<>();

//methods
Public void addFoo(){

//some code
fooList.add(this);

}

}`

wrote a method call addFoo() in 'foo' class. So now my question is what am I doing when I say arraylistObject.add(this) inside addFoo()... What am I actually doing.

Comment: You are adding a self reference of the object to the list, if you call it multiple times, you will have multiple references to the same object in your list.

Comment: But, i do not see any usecase why you want to do this. Is there any special usecase for you to do this. Bcoz it makes no sence to store the same reference in your Collection

Comment: Suppose I want to let user call this method addFoo() so as to add foo to the list then how it is going to be.

Comment: Even when the client code calls addFoo() there will bo difference. If you are expecting to save the state of the Foo object modified by client., then expose the API as `public void addFoo(Foo foo){ fooList.add(foo); }`

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below usecase which might help you.

A data structure that stores a collection of the same structure will create a tree implicitly.

```
public class TreeSample {
    private String value;
    private List<TreeSample> childNodes;

    TreeSample(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        childNodes = new LinkedList<TreeSample>();
    }

    public void addChild(TreeSample childTree) {
        this.childNodes.add(childTree);
    }

}
```

So, the client code can construct a tree data structure, by adding child trees to the parent nodes.